# Why does ls -1 not show all results?

Tags: linux, ls

I am trying to get a list of only directory names in order to store it in a variable for a foreach for processing later on.

However, just testing the `ls` first I am getting weird results.

For example:

```
ls -1 /var/lib/mysql/ | grep -e '^d'
db_nagiosql
db_nagiosql_v32
discount-o-matic
drupal
drupal5
```

However, this does what it should do:

```
ls -l /var/lib/mysql | grep -e '^d' | awk '{print $9}'
alex
bugs
bugtracker
bugzilla
cacti
cerb5
db_nagiosql
db_nagiosql_v32
discount-o-matic
drupal
drupal5
earth
fft
final_function_test
firm_ware
flyspray
gallery2
graphics
jon
joomla
mysql
nconf
old_fft
opendocman
oreon
part-number
phpbb
phpbugtracker
phplist
postnuke
teldir
test
testing
vanilla
vision
wikidb
wordpress
zen
```

The issue is, I need this to be portable(ish) so the awk part I rather not have as it may not always be the ninth column.  Why does the `ls -1` not work while the `ls -l /var/lib/mysql | grep -e '^d' | awk '{print $9}'` does work?

Comment: Why have you called `grep` in the first example, if you don't only want directories whose names start with `d`?

Comment: That explains that lol. I only want to list directories. I thought the `^d` does that? No files. No information. Just the name of the directory regardless of name listed one per line.

Comment: No, this can't be true. You wrote a whole question on SF without doing some basic research (like reading the documentation) and realising that you had misread a basic command :(

Comment: `ls -1` with a number one does not do a long listing of the entries, so the first character being a `d` only means the file/directory name starts with a `d` not that it is a directory.  if you did a `-l` (lower case `L`) instead of `1` your grep would work, but as @inukshuk's answer shows there are better ways to get just the directories

Comment: I actually had done research but misread my own comments as to what `^d` was doing.  I forgot it was from the d in the permissions rather than directory type, thus why the long listing worked and not the `ls -1`, thus why talking amongst others is a great learning experience for catching such silly mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to portably find all the directories you could use `find` like so:

```
 find /var/lib/mysql/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec basename {} \;
```

or if you have GNU (so not as portable)

```
 find /var/lib/mysql/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf "%f\n"
```

Assuming you want to further process these you might want to adapt what you're doing to be able to take the full path and let `find` help with `-print0` and `xargs -0` so you won't get tripped up with special characters in the path names.  See [why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for more info about the dangers of that road

Comment: Problem with this it returns the parent directory `mysql` as top result, but a better approach than I had done.

Comment: @Jonathan I updated my answer to fix the inclusion of the parent `mysql` directory

Comment: Since these are the actual databases I would think the problem wouldn't occur, though I never tried making a mysql db with special chars.  What I am ultimately doing, is `mysqldump`ing all the individual databases so I can recover individual databases easier rather than having EVERYTHING in one sql file dump by doing a `for` loop to iterate all the directories stored in a local variable for iteration.

Comment: @Jonathan first, you can put spaces in the names of databases like `create database \`with space\``, but it seems to not use the space in the directory name at least on the version of mysql I have running.  Second, just as a caution, the 2 `find` commands I provided actually still fall under the `don't parse ls` rule I quoted, even though they aren't using `ls`, they have the same problems unless you use the `print0` or use the `-exec` to `find` but then it depends a little on what you do in the `exec`

Comment: I'm essentially exporting the contents to a variable in a shell script so I can do a for each on it where it mysqldump each individual database from the list in the variable on a daily cron job.

Comment: @Jonathan ok, just remember it is possible for the name of the directory on disk to be different from the database name (e.g., the `with space` name I created above has a directory name `with@0020space`, since you're already handling the username and password somehow for `mysqldump` you might want to use `mysql -sNe 'show databases'` and carefully parse that output instead, with proper `read` and quoting and all

Comment: That is an interesting method, which can be must more useful in this case.  I just wish mysqldump had a better way to dump all individual databases at once, individually rather than one large dump, but i digress.  Though interestingly enough, the information_schema database does not exist in `/var/lib/mysql`

Comment: @Jonathan I found the same basic question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867520/mysqldump-with-db-in-a-separate-file which seems to offer a suggestion similar to my last comment, but also includes and answer with a possible tool you might want to consider: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10867543/4687135

Comment: I'm reading the on mobile and thus away from office but I'll certainly check that out tomorrow. Looks promising as like that person I'm reinventing the wheel unnecessarily. I have a decent bash script I'm rather proud of including retention but my only issue is obscure errors from cron. It's running on an old server and got a real panic recently. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

First, grep is matching a text pattern where ^d specifically matches all lines starting with the d character. When you do ls -l, the lines start with drwx if they are a directory, -rwx if they are a file, lrwx if they are a link, etc (give-or-take the read/write/execute permissions). When you ls -1, it's listing just the file or directory name with no other info, so grep'ing ^d will get you only files and directories that start with a d.

There are two ways to do what you're looking for:

To list only directories with the ls command, you need "ls -d */". To get your desired result, you list all the directories on one line, then remove the trailing / character if you want:

```
ls -1d */ | sed 's|/$||'
```

Or alternatively, you can use the ls -l command, grep for the directories like you did, and then awk the last column rather than the 9th column:

```
ls -l | grep ^d | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: In the last example you don't need the `grep` at all since `awk` can do pattern matching, e.g., `awk '/^d/ {print $NF}'

Comment: I am going with `ls -l /var/lib/mysql | awk '/^d/ {print $NF}'` as this does exactly what I need and more simplified than having multiple pipes.  Thank you.